# ATG RunAssembler does not package weblogic-application.xml

Tags: weblogic12c, atg, atg-dynamo

I am using ATG 11.1 with Weblogic 12c.

I have some configuration for  inside  /META-INF/weblogic-application.xml. For some reason runAssembler does not copy this xml over to the final ATG.ear in both in both standalone and non-standalone/development mode?

Also the runAssembler creats a jboss-app.xml inside the META-INF but not weblogic-application.xml

Thanks

Vivek

Answer (score 0):

The `weblogic-application.xml` is not copied by the `runAssembler` script but rather generated. This means that if you want to modify the `weblogic-application.xml` you will need to do so after the `runAssembler` has completed. If you were using `ant` to do your builds you could implement something like this:

```
<macrodef name="enable-weblogic-appplication-setting">
    <attribute name="earname" />
    <sequential>
        <available file="${ear.unpacked.dir}/${project.name}.ear/META-INF/weblogic-application.xml" property="weblogic-application.xml.found" />
        <if>
            <isset property="weblogic-application.xml.found" />
            <then>
                <replace file="${ear.unpacked.dir}/${project.name}.ear/META-INF/weblogic-application.xml">
                    <replacetoken>SomeStringThatWillAlwaysBeInTheFile</replacetoken>
                    <replacevalue>SomeStringThatWillAlwaysBeInTheFile plus TheNewValueYouWantToAdd</replacevalue>
                </replace>
            </then>
        </if>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

I've been using this approach to dynamically update elements in the `web.xml` during the assembly process.

Alternatively, if you want to use your from source code `weblogic-application.xm`l you can also use the `ant` script for `<copy file='....' tofile='...' />`.

As far as the `weblogic-application.xml` not being created by the `runAssembler` script, this is likely due to you not selecting the correct Application Server during the installation process of ATG.